# How do I manage to draw a few images in Custom View and Drag&Drop them

Tags: cocoa, draggable

I'm writting a Cocoa app. I've wrote a code that can Drag&Drop one Image. But now I need to draw several Images by double click and D&D them. Each double click- new image, each click on existing image- starts D&D. Problem is in realization. I can't imagine a simple way of realization. Can anybody propose a solution?

Thanks.

```
#import "DotView.h"


@implementation DotView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        center.x = center.y = 100.0;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
        NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
        [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
        NSRectFill(bounds);

        [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
         setImageInterpolation: NSImageInterpolationHigh];

        NSSize viewSize  = [self bounds].size;
        NSSize imageSize = { 50, 40 };

        NSPoint imageOrigin = center;
        imageOrigin.x -= imageSize.width  * 0.50;
        imageOrigin.y -= imageSize.height * 0.50;


        NSRect destRect;
        destRect.origin = imageOrigin;
        destRect.size = imageSize;

        NSString * file = @"/Users/classuser/Desktop/ded.jpg";
        NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];
        [image setFlipped:NO];

        [image drawInRect: destRect
                 fromRect: NSZeroRect
                operation: NSCompositeSourceOver
                 fraction: 1.0];

        NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:destRect];
        }
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event
{
    NSPoint point = [event locationInWindow];
        if(center.x<point.x+25 && center.x>point.x-25)
            if(center.y<point.y+20 && center.y>point.y-20)
                center = [self convertPoint:point fromView:nil];
}

- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent*)event {

    [self mouseDown:event];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Read:

[Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

and

[View Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

and

[Drag and Drop Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html)

Once you've read these, ask more targeted questions - this is a bit too broad to answer simply.